# How to change the formating options for captions of figures in lyx?

Tags: formatting, lyx

When I insert a figure in my lyx document, the caption is like "Figure 1: (caption)". How can I change this to "Figure 1 - (caption)" or "Figure 1. (caption)" in lyx ?

Comment: There are changes that you can do in the lyx editor and changes you can do to the latex code that lyx generates for you. If you change the appearance of your lyx document this doesn't necessarily makes changes to the latex code. So which change are you referring to?

Comment: I am referring about the caption that lyx generates automatically, namely,  "Figure: ". I wish I could change to "Figure -" or "Figure. " instead of "Figure:"

Comment: I don't think that you can do modify it. This string is hard coded to the editor.